# QT Reading binary file and then convert it to QString

Tags: c++, qt, file-io

I saved the QString in the file like this:

```
QString str="blabla";
QByteArray _forWrite=QByteArray::fromHex(str.toLatin1());
f.write(_forWrite); // f is the file that is opened for writing.
```

Then when I read the file I use QFile::readAll() to take the QByteArray but I don't know how to convert it to QString.

I tried to use the constructor that uses QByteArray but It didn't work out. I tried also with QByteArray::data() but same result. What I do wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work out"?  Compilation error? Runtime error?  Runtime OK but garbled data?

Comment: Why are you using [fromHex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromHex) on a string that is not hexadecimal?  :-/  That is invalid input and not checked, so it won't do what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you are calling QByteArray::fromHex at all. `toLatin1()` already return you QByteArray where each symbol encoded with one byte.

[**UPDATE**]

You should NOT call [QByteArray::fromHex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#fromHex) at all, because:

> invalid characters in the input are skipped

And invalid characters are characters that are not `the numbers 0-9 and the letters a-f`

Comment: The string is definitely `blabla` with lowercase L, as in "blah blah", not "b one a b one a".  One shouldn't be calling "fromHex" with that as input.  So there's definitely a misunderstanding here.

Comment: Yes, I just updated the answer with the reason why calling of toHex() doesn't work.

Comment: Yes that was it. I used toHex because I saw an example that used it didn't realise that toLatin1() returns QByteArray. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use QDataStream

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QDataStream>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QFile>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

        QString strToWrite = "blabla";
        QFile fileToWrite("file.bin");
        QDataStream dataStreamWriter(&fileToWrite);
        fileToWrite.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        dataStreamWriter << strToWrite;
        fileToWrite.close();

        QString strToRead = "";
        QFile fileToRead("file.bin");
        QDataStream dataStreamReader(&fileToRead);
        fileToRead.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        dataStreamReader >> strToRead;
        fileToRead.close();

        qDebug() << strToRead;

    return app.exec();
}
```

> Output : "blabla"

Comment: Thank you but I wanted without QDataStream :)

Comment: QString s = "blabla";

    QByteArray ba = s.toUtf8();
    QString s2 = QString::fromUtf8(ba);   
OR
    QByteArray ba = s.toLatin1();
    QString s2 = QString::fromLatin1(ba);

Depends on the character set you will use.